# AS3: localToGlobal with perspectiveProjection

Tags: actionscript-3, projection, perspectivecamera

It seems that if a display object has a perspective projection applied to it, calling localToGlobal gives you the wrong coordinates. In the following code, I draw a rectangle, rotate it slightly about its X axis, then draw an oval inside it using coordinates derived from localToGlobal. It works fine, until I try to apply a perspective projection, then the coordinates are all wrong. Anyone know how to get around this problem?

```
var w:uint = 300, h:uint = 150;
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
s.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
s.graphics.drawRect(-w/2,0,w,h);
s.graphics.endFill();
s.x = 275; s.y = 200; s.z = 600;
s.rotationX = -45;
addChild(s);

var point00:Point = new Point(0,0);
var point0h:Point = new Point(0,h);
var midL:Point = new Point(-w/2,h/2);
var midR:Point = new Point(w/2,h/2);

/*var VP:PerspectiveProjection = new PerspectiveProjection();
VP.fieldOfView = 55;
var p:Point = new Point(275,100);
VP.projectionCenter = p;
s.transform.perspectiveProjection = VP;*/

var o:Shape = new Shape();
o.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
o.graphics.drawEllipse(
  s.localToGlobal(midL).x,
  s.localToGlobal(point00).y,
  s.localToGlobal(midR).x - s.localToGlobal(midL).x,
  s.localToGlobal(point0h).y - s.localToGlobal(point00).y
);
addChild(o);
```

Comment: Voted down as it should. Question is pointless and should be removed. User applies 2.5D (similar to 3D) and ask question about localToGlobal method which is 2D only and will never ever produce any accurate result which is why methods like local3DToGlobal exit.

Comment: Actually, `local3DToGlobal` has the same issue. OP is pointing out that when `projectionCenter` is changed, the results from `localToGlobal` don't match. I think this is a perfectly valid question. I don't personally know the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that setting `perspectiveProjection` does not force the player to redraw the object, and `localToGlobal` depends on redraw for correct results. You can wait 1 tick like you found (`setTimeout` for 0ms or `enterFrame` for 1 frame will do it) or you can force the player to redraw using `BitmapData/draw()`:

```
// ...

s.transform.perspectiveProjection = VP;

new BitmapData(1, 1).draw(s); // forces player to redraw the sprite

var o:Shape = new Shape();
o.graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00);
o.graphics.drawEllipse(
  s.localToGlobal(midL).x,
  s.localToGlobal(point00).y,
  s.localToGlobal(midR).x - s.localToGlobal(midL).x,
  s.localToGlobal(point0h).y - s.localToGlobal(point00).y
);
addChild(o);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that isn't terrible. All you have to do is put a slight delay before the localToGlobal calls and then they will return the right coordinates. That also fixes local3DToGlobal.

Comment: Interesting, good find. It seems that setting `perspectiveProjection` does not  trigger a player redraw, which `localToGlobal` depends on. FYI a trick to force the player to redraw is to use `new BitmapData(1, 1).draw(s)`. I tested it with your code and it fixes the problem.

Comment: Upvoted your answer but also added one to expand on the "force redraw" trick. Cheers.